# setInterval to change class name on elements

Tags: reactjs

I have a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ux1jy9?file=index.js).

I have a group of text elements that I would like to fade in and out, I want to fade in the first element then fade it out and and fade in the second element to create a sort of carousel.

I have css @keyframes that will do the fading.

I was hoping to add and remove a class to each text element to use the fade animation.

So I wanted to use setInterval or something similar and select the element add the class then remove it.

How can I select the element using a class and how can I do this in the setInterval

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {

  }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const colors = [
    'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Yellow', 'Black'
  ]

  return (
    <div className='titles'>
      {colors.map((color, i) => (
        <p className={'title-'+i}>{color}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Are you going to have dynamic `colors` array or it'll always be static?

Comment: You can leverage useState to track the current index in the array of available. In your useEffect you can then use the interval to change the current index in the state. Only add the "active" class for example if the current index in state matches the index of the color.

Comment: This doesn't answer to your question directly but you might want to check out [react-spring](https://www.react-spring.io/) and look for trail. its super easy an it does what you want.